# Excel VBA and Late-Binding

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, vba

I have searched the web high and low, and read the Microsoft support very nice concept piece [**here**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245115) as well as many others.

My situation is that I have written a moderately complex excel solution using a lot of VBA on my **Office 2010** platform at work, targeted for about 900 users.

Part of it interfaces with *Powerpoint* to create some slides.

About 1/2 of our dept is on **Office 2013** now. We will remain a dual-office version shop for a while longer. So, of course when a user on *2013* uses my Excel and sends it to a *2010* user, the app crashes as *2010* cannot resolve the **"missing"** powerpoint references that *2013* implemented as that 2013 user **opened and saved** the excel file.

So, **implementing late-binding** in the Powerpoint subroutines seems to have solved the problem.

In every article I have read that discusses implementing late-binding in an Excel context, the examples are always cross-application (e.g., Excel interfacing with Outlook, Powerpoint, or Word). Further, I notice in my testing that when I open my file created in *2010*, it has references to the **Office 14.0 Object Library** and the **Excel 14.0 Object Library** (I have long since removed the Powerpoint library reference); then when I open and use it in *2013*, those references become **15.0** (no surprise).

What did raise an eyebrow though was when I transferred this file back to my 2010 environment and opened it, Excel changed the references back to **14.0**.

So, my question is:

Have I really **solved** my multi-office platform problem? Or, is there something **lurking** ahead that will bite me?

More specifically:

Do I need to **late-bind** the *Excel* application stuff (i.e., dim `xlapp as object` and then use `CreateObject`... and other examples so that everything-Excel is resolved at runtime - books, sheets, cells, etc) in an Excel application so that a future office version will always work in a backwards compatible way?

Or, as long as you are staying in that native *Excel* application, Microsoft is smart enough to handle it... as it seems to be doing now... and only worry with **late binding cross-office-application** interface code?

Sorry to be verbose. I wanted to ensure you can understand the full context.

Comment: "so that a future office version will always work in a backwards compatible way?..." - we can't tell it to you. I think even Microsoft doesn't know whether future VBA will be compatible with your current code. I think a working code is just fine now and you'll need to make it compatible with future versions of Office once you know them.

Comment: This is an opinion type of question. Yes, you will have headaches down the road. Besides versions, there are monthly patches and many other things that will go poof.  Even with very good users who follow instructions. Depending on your code and where it is home. Make a small vba/macro that calls and executes a central macro spreadsheet in its context. This will put the output in a pick up location that you grab in the macro. May need to use vbscript or powershell for plumbing.  This has the value that if one machine (where the macro resides) works correctly, all users should be good.